# Rebuilding component tree

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I'm learning JSF lifecycle from Oracle website and ran into ambiguous point concerning component tree rebuilding.

According to my understanding, the entire component tree will be rebuilt after every post-back request (including ajax) based on latest view-state saved, so my question is after having successfully rebuilt component tree from saved view-state what would server do with old component tree and old view-state, discard or store somewhere like view pooling for reusing later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the state saving mode you are using. If you are using client side state saving, the information related to the view is stored into javax.faces.ViewState hidden field parameter. When the server receives the request, it creates the view from the state, process it and write the field in the response. If you are using server side state saving, the state is stored into session, so in some cases the old state is there, but there is an algorithm that discard the old views from the session.

With JSF 2.0 Partial State Saving (PSS) the view is derived from two things: the initial state and the delta state. The initial state is derived from building the view again using facelets algoritm. So what's stored as view state is just an small fraction of the overall state. The trick is very effective indeed, so after that improvement people doesn't need to care about state size anymore with JSF. That has resulted in a very good performance compared with stateless frameworks. See [Understanding JSF Performance part 3 on JSFCentral](http://content.jsfcentral.com/c/journal/view_article_content?cmd=view&groupId=35702&articleId=73398&version=1.8)

In [Apache MyFaces 2.2](http://myfaces.apache.org/) there is a view pool algorithm. The idea is take advantage of the state saving algorithm and use it to reuse views already built. It can give you a boost in performance of about 8-10%, but third party libraries needs to be compatible with this approach. See [How to configure View Pool in Apache MyFaces](http://myfaces.apache.org/wiki/core/user-guide/configuration-of-special-features/view-pooling.html). This was thought as a solution to get the "ultimate performance", but most of the time you'll do it fine using without it.

Facelets algorithm with PSS enabled is called in two points: when the view is build or restored and before render response phase to refresh the components like c:if and so on.

Comment: So the entire component tree is rebuilt or the old component tree gets updated partially based on latest view state?

Comment: By default the entire component tree is rebuilt and then the delta state is applied. The old component tree is discarded. With the view pool the old tree is reused, but it has been confirmed that it is not as good as you may think because the JVM is quite fast creating objects. The evidence shows that from performance perspective what's matters at the end is the underlying implementation, not the concepts behind stateless/stateful. The nice part about JSF is that in most cases you don't need to care about these implementation details, so you can write the code that matters at the end.

Comment: That's very clear to me but if I have massive complex components on single page and that page heavily works with AJAX then recreating entire view after every single AJAX request is really a nightmare...

Comment: It depends on which implementation are you using and how it was done. MyFaces have some improvements that makes the components lighter, so create the component tree can be done very quickly compared with the time spent rendering the response for example. With the view pool what you are doing is cut the time required to create the component tree, but the evidence showed that the improvement is small because there are other things that are more relevant at the end. But that's the discussion, some people feel the view pool is good improvement, others just don't like it by the extra complexity

Comment: Facelets algorithm also has some tricks that reduce the component tree, grouping multiple tags into a single component, so even if you have a lot of html markup in you pages, the component tree can be relatively small, so the ajax is not really as heavy as you may think. It is surprising how many people I have found, that have the wrong idea about performance, but once they see the data and the code, they change their mind because you can't fight against that.

Comment: Html elements are not counted as components in component tree, right? So you meant grouping html tags into single JSF component or JSF component tags in single JSF component?

Comment: A chunk of continues html markup counts as 1 component, but this one is special, because it is a wrapper without state, very light. You can use ui:debug to see how the component tree is built and how many components your view really has. In few words, the algorithm groups multiple html tags into a single JSF component.